# Code to perform an attack to a CNN with foolbox, what's wrong?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have to perform a simple FSGM attack to a convolutional neural network. The code for the CNN works correctly, and the model is saved without a problem, but when i try to perform the attack an error is shown.

HERE'S THE CODE FOR THE CNN

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import json
import tensorflow as tf
#Using TensorFlow backend.

#download mnist data and split into train and test sets

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

#plot the first image in the dataset
plt.imshow(X_train[0])
#check image shape
X_train[0].shape
#reshape data to fit model
X_train = X_train.reshape(60000,28,28,1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(10000,28,28,1)
#one-hot encode target column
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

y_train[0]
#create model
model = Sequential()
#add model layers
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu', input_shape= (28,28,1)))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
#compile model using accuracy as a measure of model performance
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics= ['accuracy'])

#train model
model.fit(X_train, y_train,validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=5)

json.dump({'model':model.to_json()},open("model.json", "w"))
model.save_weights("model_weights.h5")
```

THEN I TRY TO PERFORM THE ATTACK WITH THE FOLLOWING CODE:

```
import json
import foolbox
import keras
import numpy as np
from keras import backend
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils import np_utils
from foolbox.attacks import FGSM
from foolbox.criteria import Misclassification
from foolbox.distances import MeanSquaredDistance
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import model_from_json
import os



############## Loading the model and preprocessing #####################

backend.set_learning_phase(False)

model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(json.load(open("model.json"))["model"],custom_objects={})
model.load_weights("model_weights.h5")
fmodel = foolbox.models.KerasModel(model, bounds=(0,1))
_,(images, labels) = mnist.load_data()

images = images.reshape(10000,28,28)
images= images.astype('float32')
images /= 255

######################### Attacking the model ##########################

attack=foolbox.attacks.FGSM(fmodel, criterion=Misclassification())
adversarial=attack(images[12],labels[12]) # for single image
adversarial_all=attack(images,labels) # for all the images
adversarial =adversarial.reshape(1,28,28,1) #reshaping it for model prediction

model_predictions = model.predict(adversarial)
print(model_predictions)


########################## Visualization ################################
images=images.reshape(10000,28,28)
adversarial =adversarial.reshape(28,28)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.title('Original')
plt.imshow(images[12])
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.title('Adversarial')
plt.imshow(adversarial)
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
plt.title('Difference')
difference = adversarial - images[124]
plt.imshow(difference / abs(difference).max() * 0.2 + 0.5)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

this error is shown when the adversarial examples are generated:

```
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status)) 
InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,639232], In[1]: [1024,10]
[[{{node dense_4_5/MatMul}}]]
[[{{node dense_4_5/BiasAdd}}]]
```

What could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution.

First of all modify the model code as follows

```
import tensorflow as tf
import json
# download mnist data and split into train and test sets
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
# reshape data to fit model
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_train, X_test = X_train/255, X_test/255
# one-hot encode target column
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)
# create model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
# add model layers
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5),
                                 activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
# compile model using accuracy as a measure of model performance
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# train model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=5)

json.dump({'model': model.to_json()}, open("model.json", "w"))
model.save_weights("model_weights.h5")
```

You just forgot to divide each pixel by the maximum value of RGB (255)

As for the attacker code

```
import json
import foolbox
from foolbox.attacks import FGSM
from foolbox.criteria import Misclassification
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


############## Loading the model and preprocessing #####################
tf.enable_eager_execution()
tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(False)

model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(
    json.load(open("model.json"))["model"], custom_objects={})
model.load_weights("model_weights.h5")
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

_, (images, labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
images = images.reshape(images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
images = images/255
images = images.astype(np.float32)

fmodel = foolbox.models.TensorFlowEagerModel(model, bounds=(0, 1))


######################### Attacking the model ##########################

attack = foolbox.attacks.FGSM(fmodel, criterion=Misclassification())
adversarial = np.array([attack(images[0], label=labels[0])])

model_predictions = model.predict(adversarial)
print('real label: {}, label prediction; {}'.format(
    labels[0], np.argmax(model_predictions)))
```

I used TensorFlowEagerModel instead of KerasModel for simplicty. The error you were encountering was due to the fact that model.predict expects a 4d matrix while you were passing a 3d matrix, so I just wrapped up the attack to the image example into a numpy array to make it 4d.

Hope it helps